# AdSense graphics.js TypeError

Tags: javascript, error-handling, adsense

I'm try to place adsense code to my website and get next error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null in graphics.js line 17
```

Also this error break site loading in opera browser.

Ad type is text and display ads.

Any tips how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Goran Aleksic here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/zwwiit4btiE/sUeRGEfmgQoJ